# Get sideloaded records in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model with hasMany relationship:

```
App.Offer = DS.Model.extend({
shop: DS.attr('number'),          //ext key
name: DS.attr('string'),
description: DS.attr('number'),

products: DS.hasMany('product', {embedded: true})
});

App.Product = DS.Model.extend({
name: DS.attr('string'),
description: DS.attr('string'),
});
```

The record are sideloaded by the server and if I use them in templates it works:

```
{{#each product in model.products}}
    <li>{{product.nome}} - {{product.descrizione}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

But what if I want load the products into an array in the controller?

```
actions: {
    var products = [];

    $.each(this.get('model').get('products'), function(index, value) {
        products[index] = value.get('nome');  //this doesn't work
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do it like this:

```
actions: {
    var products = [];

    this.get('model').get('products').forEach(function(product) {
        products[index] = product;
    });
}
```

But you really shouldn't do it that way.  There shouldn't be a need to create a new array.  Just fetching `this.get('model').get('products')` should return an object with all the models and the ability to iterate or do whatever you like with it.

Comment: This doesn't work: this.get('model').get('products').forEach(function(product) { console.log(product) });         It logs nothing

Comment: Is this.get('model').get('products') returning anything?

Comment: No, it was returning undefined, but i works after using async: true instead of embedded: always... I still have to figure out why...